# Images doesn't scale up or down in the same ratio React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, svg, html-table

I was trying to build a React page for mobile and Web views. I've put an image for nonveg and veg Symbols on a table rendering the data. But when viewed from different-sized screens, the Non-Veg icon scales up larger than the Veg icon. Any solutions for it?

How it looks on S sized screen:

[image]

How it looks on a M sized:

[image]

On a L size:

[image]

My react HTML Code:

```
<thead className='DVthead'>
        <tr className='DVtr'>
        <th className='DVth'>Food</th>
          <th className='DVth'><img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74299799/210125736-3e021162-9217-4f6c-9d61-f9aceaa6e468.svg" alt='NON-VEG' /></th>
          <th className='DVth'><img src="https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/74299799/210125735-9d1831f4-28e3-4a8a-885a-0493de559372.svg" alt='VEG'  /></th>
          <th className='DVth'>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
```

CSS:

```
   .DVtd,  .DVth {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .DVtr{
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .DVth {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  }

  .DVth img {
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    
  }
```

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what style you have applied for `DVimgg` class ?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to style using `className`. It didn't work so I removed it. I'll edit the Question

Comment: can you try setting width and height for `<img width={50} height={50}>` tag.

Comment: I did that. Its working for all Size pretty fine but not the S size Screen of dimension 320x829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the CSS something like:

```css
th.DVth img{
    width: 200%; // needed only if image size is smaller than required and can be adjusted according to requirement
    height: 200%; // same as above
    max-height: 30px; // required height
}
```

Comment: Yours is working but the problem persists on laptop screens. I figured I can use @mediaQueries to sort that. Thank you.